# Oracle sql find similar strings using Soundex

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table HumanNames

The input is

```
|HumanName      |
|-------------  |
|Kamil          |
|Azer           |
|John           |
|Elmir          |
|Kamal          |
|Elmar          |
|Orxan          |
|Elnar          |
```

I need write query which will give result names of like another name.
Desired output is

```
|NamesWhichLikes  |
|-------------    |
|Kamil,Kamal      |
|Elmir,Elmar,Elnar|
|                 |
```

Comment: Please edit the question to clarify the logic you need. As is, it's completely unclear

Comment: How do you define similar? By the number of different chars? Considering upper/lower case? ...

Comment: You say that "Kamil" is similar to "Kamal" and "Elmir" is similar to "Elmar" and "Elnar". Why? It's up to you to explain the logic behind your needed result.

Comment: "Kamil" and "Kamal" have 5 chars, with 4 equal chars. So 80%, not 90%.

Comment: If that is your definition of similarity then you will probably need to do this procedurally rather than SQL. Soundex could give you two words spelled very differently but that 'sound' similar breaking your 90% similar criteria. UTL_MATCH.JARO_WINKLER will give you a standard mathematical similarity but you will need to understand the rules.

Comment: Your need is still not completely clear. You say that Elmir,Elmar,Elnar are similar because Elmir differs from Elmar by 1 char (80%), Elmar differs from Elnar from 1 char(80%), but Elmir differs from Elnar by 2 chars (60%). If you keep applying this logic, you may say that are similar Elmir->Elmar->Elnar->ElnaX->ElnXX->ElXXX->EXXXX->XXXXX. And I believe this is not your need

Comment: As Aleksej demonstrates, the whole concept is meaningless. You can show pairs where the difference is no more than 80%, but that relation is not transitive, so it makes no sense to "associate" because there is a "middle man" that is "associated with both." Will you consider Elmir and Elnar to be similar if in your table you also have an Elmar, but not otherwise? How does that make any sense?

Comment: Using SOUNDEX will also mean that any name that is indeed similar but has a different first character will not be flagged as similar, e.g. Hayley / Ailee.  A very simple requirement of 'similar names' very quickly becomes extremely complex. Maybe understanding WHY you need the list would be beneficial.

Comment: Folks, READ WHAT SOUNDEX DOES and don't downvote questions YOU don't understand!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this using `listagg` and `group by` on `soundex` of name:

```
with your_table (HumanName) as (
select 'Kamil' from dual union all 
select 'Azer'  from dual union all 
select 'John'  from dual union all 
select 'Elmir' from dual union all 
select 'Kamal' from dual union all 
select 'Elmar' from dual union all 
select 'Orxan' from dual union all 
select 'Elnar' from dual
)
------ Test data setup ends here ------


select
    listagg(humanname,',') within group (order by humanname) nameswhichlikes
from your_table
group by soundex(humanname)
having count(*) > 1;
```

Produces:

```
+---------------------------+
| NAMESWHICHLIKES           |
+---------------------------+
| Elmar,Elmir,Elnar         |
+---------------------------+
| Kamal,Kamil               |
+---------------------------+
```

In case of duplicate names:

```
select
    listagg(humanname,',') within group (order by humanname) nameswhichlikes
from (select distinct humanname from your_table)
group by soundex(humanname)
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Just use `distinct humanname` in subquery and then apply the above on it

Comment: Please post those inputs, on which it doesn't work. Plus it's on you to decide which algo to use for determining which strings are similar. Just swap soundex with that function

Comment: And only works where names have the same first letter.

Comment: Stop flaming, Sponge&Bob!

Comment: @BriteSponge You can change `group by soundex(humanname)` with something like `group by soundex('xxx' || humanname)` to do a passable job at accounting for that.  Try it with "George", "Jurg",and "Jorge", for example.